# Best way to store multiple query selectors in one variable

Tags: javascript

I have some simple HTML here:

```
<div class='one'>
  <p>one</p>
  <p>one</p>
  <p>one</p>
</div>

<div class='two'>
  <p>two</p>
  <p>two</p>
  <p>two</p>
</div>
```

And a simple couple of query selectors here:

```
var nodes = [],
    ones = document.querySelectorAll('.one p'),
    twos = document.querySelectorAll('.two p');

nodes = [...ones, ...twos];

console.log(nodes.length);
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ns91/pen/WNvJyjV

The code nodes variable achieves what I want to: a concatenation of the two node lists. Is there a better way of writing this for brevity? If I'm correct, you cannot use the concat method on node lists as they're array specific - and using the spread operator makes it incompatible with IE.

Thanks for any advice here.

Comment: If you just want to use your example but want to support IE you can use this polyfill just put it above all of your script tags to make sure the browser loads it first https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-polyfills/0.1.42/polyfill.min.js

Comment: Or `var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(ones).concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(twos));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not a single `querySelectorAll()` with both the selectors:

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.one p, .two p');
console.log(nodes.length);
```

```html
<div class='one'>
  <p>one</p>
  <p>one</p>
  <p>one</p>
</div>

<div class='two'>
  <p>two</p>
  <p>two</p>
  <p>two</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work in IE or older versions of browser you have to use a polyfill

Comment: @HusseinAl-Mosawi, do you really want the support for ie<8? I really find them hard now-a-days!

Comment: it's just a reminder for the OP and the others that are coming here

Comment: We only have to support IE11. Very nice JS even if we didn't need to support IE though! Thank you

Comment: @user8758206, removing `Array.from` should work in ie11, updated the answer, please check:)